# Combining Match and Offset

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to use match function to find a value (say, value in A3) from a named range, and then use offset to give the value right of the value searched, from the named range. The named range is called "CATEGORY"
I've written something like this:

=OFFSET(MATCH(CATEGORY, A3, 0)), 1, 1, 1, 1)

Its not working, how do I make it work?

Comment: `CATEGORY` - is a _single row_ range?

Comment: `MATCH` returns a number; `OFFSET` needs a range as reference. 

Also, `MATCH` requires a value as the first argument and a range as the second.

Comment: CATEGORY is a single column range

Comment: right, A3 before category, but how do I make offset refer to the cell reference that match is arriving at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MATCH` returns a number; `OFFSET` needs a range as reference.

Also, `MATCH` requires a value as the first argument and a range as the second.

The following works

```
=OFFSET(category, MATCH(A3, category,0)-1, 1)
```

assuming that you are looking for the value in `A3` in the column `CATEGORY`

Note that `MATCH` returns `1` for the first cell - so you need to subtract one to stay on the same line; similarly, you need a column offset of `+1` to get "cell to the right". The `0` third argument for `MATCH` means "exact match".

Example of this formula at work:

[image]

Comment: +1, btw OP edited their post and now `the value right of the value searched` required

Comment: @simoco thanks for pointing that out. I was sure I had read "to the left" when I was composing my answer. Have now updated to reflect the edited question.

Comment: I was fidgeting with those too!

Comment: Does it have a match?